# Problema com acentuação no IIS 10 (Windows 10) usando ASP clássico

Tags: iis, asp

Fiz várias pesquisas há 2 dias e tentei de tudo mas não consegui resolver o problema, que é o seguinte:

eu ativei o IIS no Windows 10 home 64 bits para usar páginas locais em ASP clássico. Até aí tudo beleza, funcionando direitinho, porém percebi que ao enviar um texto com acentuação através de um `POST` num formulário e capturando ele por um `REQUEST`, onde tem acento ele retorna caracteres estranhos, como se o servidor não reconhecesse acentos.

Por exemplo: a palavra "*capítulo*" vem no `REQUEST` como "capï¿½tulo", e no banco MySQL é gravado como "cap?tulo". Se eu coloco a `QUERY` direto na URL (Ex. ?nome=capítulo), o `REQUEST` retorna errado também "capÃ­tulo" mas grava corretamente no banco de dados.

Sou um pouco inexperiente nisso e já fucei tudo e não consegui resolver. Alguém saberia como corrigir isso?

Comment: O seu problema parece ser **_encoding_** (inglês). Olharia configurações de _localização_ ou _globalização_ no IIS e no MySQL a opção **CHARACTER SET**. Recomendo a leitura do texto [O Mínimo Absoluto que todos os Programadores de Software precisam, absoluta e positivamente, saber sobre Unicode e conjuntos de caracteres (sem desculpas!) — The Joel on Software Translation Project](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado pela ajuda mas consegui resolver. O problema não era na configuração do servidor. Era uma `include` que estava sem o `charset`, e por isso "bagunçando" o resto da página.